# From where can i download cakephp email component?

Tags: php, email, components, cakephp-1.3, download

I am struggling with downloading mail component for cakephp 1.3.From where can i download cakephp email component ?

Comment: Hey Lak, Its supposed to be a core component, meaning it should already be included in Cake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email component is built in, no need to download or install.

Just make sure it's in the $components array for the controller and you're all set.

Check out the docs for more info. http://book.cakephp.org/view/1283/Email